# eliminating fall off in weight paint?

Tags: texture-painting, weight-painting

Is there a way to get the weight paint stroke to be constant instead of having a fall off? I tried messing around with the fall off curves but that doesn't work. Essentially I want to weight paint with just the red and blue values and nothing in between.

Answer (score 2):

Since the last versions you'll always have a gradient between a vertex and the next one, for example here the left vertex is 1 and the one on its right is 0 and you can see a gradient between these 2 even though there are no vertices between them:

[image]

Comment: thank you for the info!